# How to wrap text in pygame using pygame.font.Font()?

Tags: python, fonts, formatting, pygame

I am making a would you rather game, and I would like to not have character restrictions for the W.Y.R. questions. I have seen many examples here on Stack Overflow and other websites, but they use other modules and methods I don't understand how to use or want to use. So I would rather use

```py
button_text_font = pygame.font.Font(font_location, 20)
red_button_text = button_text_font.render(red_text, True, bg_color)
blue_button_text = button_text_font.render(blue_text, True, bg_color)
```

I would like to know how to use this method and, for example, somehow input how far the text can go until it wraps to the next line.

Thanks

P.S. If you could, please also include centering text, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is adapted from some very old code I wrote:

```
def renderTextCenteredAt(text, font, colour, x, y, screen, allowed_width):
    # first, split the text into words
    words = text.split()

    # now, construct lines out of these words
    lines = []
    while len(words) > 0:
        # get as many words as will fit within allowed_width
        line_words = []
        while len(words) > 0:
            line_words.append(words.pop(0))
            fw, fh = font.size(' '.join(line_words + words[:1]))
            if fw > allowed_width:
                break

        # add a line consisting of those words
        line = ' '.join(line_words)
        lines.append(line)

    # now we've split our text into lines that fit into the width, actually
    # render them

    # we'll render each line below the last, so we need to keep track of
    # the culmative height of the lines we've rendered so far
    y_offset = 0
    for line in lines:
        fw, fh = font.size(line)

        # (tx, ty) is the top-left of the font surface
        tx = x - fw / 2
        ty = y + y_offset

        font_surface = font.render(line, True, colour)
        screen.blit(font_surface, (tx, ty))

        y_offset += fh
```

The basic algorithm is to split the text into words and iteratively build up lines word by word checking the resulting width each time and splitting to a new line when you would exceed the width.

As you can query how wide the rendered text will be, you can figure out where to render it to centre it.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. This algorithm looks very handy, but could you add comments to describe each line, because I don't know how to incorporate this into my game.

Comment: Re-written (and actually tested now :) ) as a function with comments and (marginally) better variable naming.

Comment: Thanks! You've been very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

This is messy and there is far more you can do but if you want a specific length of text for say a paragraph...

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman, Arial", 20, bold=True)
your_text = "blah blah blah"
txtX, txtY = 125, 500
wraplen = 50
count = 0
my_wrap = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=wraplen)
wrap_list = my_wrap.wrap(text=your_text)
# Draw one line at a time further down the screen
for i in wrap_list:
    txtY = txtY + 35
    Mtxt = font.render(f"{i}", True, (255, 255, 255))
    WIN.blit(Mtxt, (txtX, txtY))
    count += 1

# Update All Window and contents
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: `textwrap` and `WIN` aren't defined in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Using the implementation in [Pygame Zero](https://github.com/lordmauve/pgzero/blob/master/pgzero/ptext.py#L81-L143), text can be wrapped with the following function.

```
# Adapted from https://github.com/lordmauve/pgzero/blob/master/pgzero/ptext.py#L81-L143
def wrap_text(text, font, max_width):
    texts = text.replace("\t", "    ").split("\n")
    lines = []

    for text in texts:
        text = text.rstrip(" ")

        if not text:
            lines.append("")
            continue

        # Preserve leading spaces in all cases.
        a = len(text) - len(text.lstrip(" "))

        # At any time, a is the rightmost known index you can legally split a line. I.e. it's legal
        # to add text[:a] to lines, and line is what will be added to lines if
        # text is split at a.
        a = text.index(" ", a) if " " in text else len(text)
        line = text[:a]

        while a + 1 < len(text):
            # b is the next legal place to break the line, with `bline`` the
            # corresponding line to add.
            if " " not in text[a + 1:]:
                b = len(text)
                bline = text
                
            else:
                # Lines may be split at any space character that immediately follows a non-space
                # character.
                b = text.index(" ", a + 1)
                while text[b - 1] == " ":
                    if " " in text[b + 1:]:
                        b = text.index(" ", b + 1)
                    else:
                        b = len(text)
                        break
                bline = text[:b]

            bline = text[:b]

            if font.size(bline)[0] <= max_width:
                a, line = b, bline

            else:
                lines.append(line)
                text = text[a:].lstrip(" ")
                a = text.index(" ", 1) if " " in text[1:] else len(text)
                line = text[:a]

        if text:
            lines.append(line)

    return lines
```

Bear in mind that wrapping text requires multiple lines that must be rendered separately. Here's an example of how you could render each line.

```
def create_text(text, color, pos, size, max_width=None, line_spacing=1):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", size)

    if max_width is not None:
        lines = wrap_text(text, font, max_width)
    else:
        lines = text.replace("\t", "    ").split("\n")

    line_ys = (
        np.arange(len(lines)) - len(lines) / 2 + 0.5
    ) * 1.25 * font.get_linesize() + pos[1]

    # Create the surface and rect that make up each line
    text_objects = []

    for line, y_pos in zip(lines, line_ys):
        text_surface = font.render(line, True, color)
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=(pos[0], y_pos))
        text_objects.append((text_surface, text_rect))

    return text_objects


# Example case
lines = create_text(
    text="Some long text that needs to be wrapped",
    color=(255, 255, 255),  # White
    pos=(SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2),  # Center of the screen
    size=16,
    max_width=SCREEN_WIDTH,
)

# Render each line
for text_object in lines:
    screen.blit(*text_object)
```